# Process Collection through Map function

Tags: laravel, collections

I get a Collection from a Query in Laravel.

Actually, I'm processing collection like that:

```
foreach ($cts as $ct) {
        $array[$ct->id] = $ct->category->name;

    }
```

It outputs this:

```
array:2 [▼
1158 => "Junior por Equipo"
1160 => "Varonil por Equipo"
]
```

Now, I would like to user map() function over muy collection as I like it better:

```
MyModel::get()
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($item, $value){
            return [ $item->id => $item->category->name ];
        })->toArray();
```

But now, I get :

```
    array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    1158 => "Junior por Equipo"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    1160 => "Varonil por Equipo"
  ]
]
```

How should I do to output it like the first case?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to map the collection,  just use `MyModel::lists('name',  'id' ) ;`

Comment: ok, but how should I do to resolve id to name ( name is in another table ) . I will have MyModel::get()->pluck('category_id','id') but not MyModel::get()->pluck('category_name,'id')

Comment: id is no problem, but how should I use the other field is in another table, so I can't use pluck / lists anymore :(

Comment: Try this `MyModel::with('relationship')->lists('related_table.id', 'mymodel_table. id' ) `

Answer (score 0):

There is a collection method for that. `pluck()` and eloquent `lists()`

no its preferred to use pluck for getting some columns only. previously lists() was used.

see https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-pluck

as the document says

The pluck method retrieves all of the values for a given key/keys only

so it would be something like this.

```
Model::get()->pluck('name','id);
```

Than you can do toArray() on the result if you want to get an array instead of a collection.

Comment: Not working...In my case, I can do it with id, but the other field is a relation, so it is outside the model, so pluck doesn't work